# Special characters in column names

Tags: php, mysql, special-characters

I got a database from a customer and need to create some logic around it, like reading and inserting entries.

When I tried some basic requests, like:

```
$json = array ();
$query = "select * from tab1";

if ($result = $link->query ( $query )) {
    while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc () ) {
        array_push ( $json, $row );
    }
}

die ( json_encode ( $json ) );
```

I surprisingly got an empty response.

Executing the same query directly from PHPMyAdmin, I got all expected results.

When I just dumped the JSON result in the browser, I noticed (extract):

```
... string(30) "ColumnName(�)"  ...
```

It took me a while to find out, that there were columns name with some special charaters, like `µ` and `°`. Apparently, they could not be displayed properly so the whole response became invalid and I got no results.

Just removing those characters from the column name solved the problem.

Is there another solution, instead of just manually looking for those characters and removing them?

Comment: There's no inherent problem with special characters in column names. What exactly is your code doing?

Comment: Set connection charset to utf8 (utf8mb4 is the real unicode charset in mysql, so use that if you want) and put table and column names in backticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `json_encode()`/`json_decode()` deals only with **UTF-8** encoding, you must convert all non utf8 encoded string to utf-8

You can use [utf8-encode() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)